# Service worker with workbox and Gulp, how to add my own rules?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I just started to work with workbox and I am using Gulp to generate my service worker with the following code in the example: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/get-started/gulp

It generates the service-worker file properly, but the thing I do not understand is how can I add my own code to the file? Lets say I want to add the following route:

```js
workboxSW.router.registerRoute(
  'https://pixabay.com/get/(.*)',
  cacheOneWeekStrategy
);
```

Now if I run the gulp task again it overwrites my own route. How can I add my own code? I also want to add some event listeners etc.

Update: so far I have found out that I can use injectManifest() which will inject routes to the file inside workboxSW.precache([]); But I still need to copy the actual service worker script somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out any other way. This is my solution. I copy workbox from node_modules and then I write my code to sw.js and then I use inject-manifest to inject the routes to my own code.

```js
gulp.task('copy-workbox', () => {
  return gulp.src(['node_modules/workbox-sw/build/importScripts/workbox-sw.prod*.js'])
    .pipe(rename('workbox.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});

gulp.task('inject-manifest', () => {
  return wbBuild.injectManifest({
    swSrc: './app/sw.js',
    swDest: './app/service-worker.js',
    globDirectory: './app/',
    globPatterns: ['**\/*.{html,js,css,png}'],
    globIgnores: ['admin.html']
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Service worker generated.');
  });
});
```

UPDATE: after some reading I figured out it is not a good idea to rename the workbox. However I couldn't find a way to do this otherwise.

Comment: I have created a plugin gulp-workbox that can solve your problem; check it out!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit of a sticky point for earlier versions of Workbox.

Workbox v3 provides some more options to make this easier.

1. There is a CDN you can use: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started
2. To host the files yourself, you can use `copyWorkboxLibraries()` which will save the files to a specific location and returns the path of the files ([More details here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#.copyWorkboxLibraries))